# Разделение массива на два новых javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Дан массив `["Banana", "Cherry", "Melon", "Strawberry"]`. Необходимо отсортировать его и в два новых массива добавить значения: ягоды в массив "berrys", все остальные значения - в массив "other".  Сортировка через sort и т.д. дает только один новый массив. Подскажите, как вывести два новых? Может, как-то применить конструкцию swich:case?

Comment: то что ты хочешь это **НЕ** сортировка, это группировка. Группировка обычно происходит по какому-то признаку, здесь непонятно какой признак должен быть у строки, чтобы поместить ее в массив ягод

Comment: ну, учебные задания на понимание, что поделать. Я тоже не могла понять, по какому признаку разделять, но, видимо, надо действительно исходить из того, что нам известны все переменные массива

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выборка производится по окончанию слова на 'erry'
Берутся элементы с 4 элемента с конца и до самого конца

```
let arr = ["Banana", "Cherry", "Melon", "Strawberry"];
let berries = [];
let other = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].slice(-4) === 'erry') {
    berries.push(arr[i]);   
  }
  else {
    other.push(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Если добавить в массив 'Blackcurrant', то вся логика сломается. :)

Comment: Круто, конечно, тырить чужой ответ, менять в нём одну строчку и выдавать за свой :(( что-нибудь  оригинальное предложить слабо?

Comment: Это самый логичный ответ используя цикл и условие

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку непонятно, по какому признаку отличать ягоды от остальных, можно сортировать по названию (если, конечно, заранее известно, какие ягоды в массиве):

```js
var arr = ["Banana", "Cherry", "Melon", "Strawberry"];
var berries = [];
var othres = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] == "Cherry" || arr[i] == "Strawberry") {
        berries.push(arr[i]);
    }
    else {
       othres.push(arr[i]);
    }
}

console.log(berries);
console.log(othres);
```